# What's a good way to create a Form Filler?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

While applying for jobs, I find that it's extremely tedious to fill out the same things over and over again (I'm talking specifically about Taleo, where Autofill never quite cuts it).

I read that Taleo has staffed about 15% of the current workforce, so hundreds, maybe thousands (*maybe* ***millions***) of people have experienced the same tedium of uploading a resume, then filling out the same information again and again and again and again. Read some [complaints.](https://www.reddit.com/r/jobs/comments/2y4pv3/seriously_people_that_apply_to_jobs_on_the_daily/)

So, as someone with almost no coding experience, I'd like to brush up on a useful skill while creating something to help people.

So, I want to create a Chrome extension (using Json, Javascript & HTML) that:

- Creates a popup with all the same fields as Taleo (using their HTML
  tags from their page source)
- Saves that info into an HTML file as a bookmark
- Populates an application form using that information

My questions are:
Is there a way to permanently save all the information entered into a form so I don't have to save it as a bookmark?
Is there a simpler (and as accurate) way to do this?

My end goal is to fill out all the information once, and then fill every subsequent job application with one click (and also to practice coding).

Comment: A userscript would probably be easier and applicable to not only Chrome. You can store the information in [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API). There’s no need for a bookmark.

Comment: Awesome, I'll look into that.